# открыть dropdown с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, есть бутстраповский dropdow. При success ajax запросе нужно открыть его (т.е. без клика по чему-то). Как это реализовать? Пробывал присвоить класс open, дропдаун открывается но не закрывается при клике на сайт.

```
<span class="dropdown search-dropdown">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropd-search" style="margin: 2px -107px;">
            <form>
            <div class="search-users">
            <div class="search-users-block">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-link hover" onclick="$('#search-icon').click();">
            {gosearch}
            <img src="/incl/img/icons/right_icon.svg" id="right-icon">
            </div>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </span>
```

Comment: Сделайте демо на jsfiddle, так будет проще понять проблему и помочь

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить класс к елементу для открытия списка

```
    success: function() {
      $( '.dropdown' ).addClass('open'); //Вместо "open" подставьте нужный класс.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов, первый - менять свойство display с none на flex/block. Второй способ прописать все в css используя input type checkbox, со свойством checked. Также можно сгенерировать DOM при помощи javascript.